# Serilog conditional template headers

Tags: serilog

Is there a way to conditionally include strings in a Serilog template?
For example,

```
_logger.Information("Event: {evt} Description: {dsc}", evt, dsc}
```

How do I omit the "Description:" string if dsc is null or empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [message template](https://messagetemplates.org/) is definitely a fixed point in the equation.

If the `description` is an ancillary field for you, you could do

```
_logger.ForContext("Description",dsc).Information("Event: {evt}", evt}
```

... if you do this, be sure to include `{Properties}` in log rendering format string to include context fields such as this which are not used in the actual message template.

Other than that, you're left with a humble `if`:

```
if(desc!=null)
    _logger.Information("Event: {evt} Description: {dsc}", evt, dsc}
else
    _logger.Information("Event: {evt}", evt);
```

Note, this will yield a different message template id in the message under the hood for obvious reasons, which may be a reason to prefer the former.

(Also not possible is the ternary operator instead of `if` - that will run you into trouble with the [Serilog Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Suchiman.SerilogAnalyzer))

Comment: "humble if" is a very witty expression